# How to execute a Command from a different project in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am a newbie to WPF and am trying to create a simple test app, while maintaining an MVVM architecture.
So I split the application into two distinct projects: Tomato.UI (which contains the xaml files) and Tomato.ViewModels (which contains the classes to manage the interaction with the view).

For now I only have two files for one window: MainWindow.xaml and MainWindowViewModel.cs
[image]

In addition I added a reference to Tomato.ViewModels from Tomato.UI

[image]

So this is the MainWindow.xaml, where I've created a reference to the ViewModels namespace and where a Button is bound to a function on the MainWindowViewModel.cs file:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Tomato.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Tomato.ViewModels"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Content="START" 
            Click="ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel.ButtonStartClick" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="344,304,343.6,70" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="106" Height="46">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the related ViewModel class I have the following code

```c#
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Tomato.Utils;

namespace Tomato.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {

        public ICommand ButtonStartClick { get; set; }


        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ButtonStartClick = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(ButtonStart));
        }

        private void ButtonStart(object sender)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Starting now!");
        }

    }
}
```

But when I try to execute the code I get this error that I can't solve:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ButtonStartClick' and no accessible extension method 'ButtonStartClick' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Tomato.UI   C:\Projects_personal\TomatoTimer\TomatoTimer\MainWindow.xaml   26  Active

A heartfelt thanks to anyone who is able to direct me on the right path :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to make a binding `Command="{Binding ButtonStartClick}"`

Click is an eventhandler, not command.

```
<Button Content="START"
   Command="{Binding ButtonStartClick}"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="344,304,343.6,70"
   VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="106" Height="46">
</Button>
```

Check you have setted correctly the DataContext for the Window (not for the button, the button inherits the datacontext of the parent if not setted).

Answer (score 1):

> I am a newbie to WPF and am trying to create a simple test app, while maintaining an MVVM architecture

Unfortunately, so far you're doing it wrong. :)

With the syntax you've tried to use the XAML, the property would have to be `static`, accessible through the type name itself. But the way you've declared your view model class, you need to reference a property path on binding markup, for a data context object that has been instantiated.

Note that currently, your XAML also doesn't declare a view model object. That can be done in a variety of ways, but the most straightforward would be to set the `Windows.DataContext` property.

Putting that all together, you get something like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Tomato.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Tomato.ViewModels"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Content="START" 
            Command="{Binding ButtonStartClick}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="344,304,343.6,70" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="106" Height="46">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The View needs to bind to the view model instance in the `DataContext`, which, in this case, can all be done in XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Tomato.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Tomato.ViewModels;assembly=Tomato.ViewModels"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel /> <!-- Set DataContext to View Model-->
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Content="START" 
            Command="{Binding ButtonStartClick}" <!-- Bind to command -->
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="344,304,343.6,70" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="106" Height="46" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```